# How to tell if there is no content to be read from an HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson

I'm currently reading data from a REST service I've created. The data returned is `List<String>`. The List is populated with YAML file contents which were extracted into a map and then to the list.

When the get call returns something (i.e. there's content in the List object), my code works perfectly. When nothing is returned, I get a java.net.UnknownServiceException: no content type

The List is used to populate HTML selectors. When nothing is returned, no selectors should appear. I currently have this working by catching the exception and continuing with the AJAX call as shown below. I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do it (like checking if there's content in the returned InputStream).

```
URL url = new URL("myurl");
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openconnection();
request.connect();

try{
   //parse
   JsonParser jp = new.JsonParser();
   JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
   JsonArray unsanitizedMembers = root.getAsJsonArray();

   //remove quotes from input
   List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int i=0; i<unsanitizedMembers.size(); i++)
      members.add(unsanitizedMembers.get(i).getAsString());

   //add to thymeleaf model
   model.addAttributes("members", members);
}
catch(UnknownServiceException e){
   //return nothing if given list is empty
   return "fragments :: memberResults";
}
return "fragments :: memberResults";
```

Edit: I feel my error might stem from what map objects return when the get method finds no index. So here's generally what my REST service is doing (note the variable "role" is given in the URL request):

```
//input YML file
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourcesAsStream("roles.yml");
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

//convert to map object
Map<String, List<String>> map = (Map<String, List<String>>) yaml.load(inputStream);

//return list of strings
return map.get(role);
```

Comment: You read the content and it's empty?

Comment: Why don't you check if content is `null`?

Comment: @RC. The UnknownServiceException means [the protocol does not support the content type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContent%28%29). If you're talking about the request.getContent() I haven't been able to get it to work as a check.

Answer (score 0):

Check if content is `null`. Maybe like this:

```
if (request.getContent() != null)
    JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
```

Comment: the if statement generates a java.net.UnknownServiceException: no content-type

Comment: @Brandon have you tried checking for `request.responseCode`? Then you can see if it Http204

Comment: the response code is 200 no matter if there is content or not. You had me hopeful on this one though!